# Annotations in YouTube unusable in Windows 7 with Firefox & IE

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, youtube, annotations

Anyone know why I can't use annotations anymore in my videos in YouTube?

I have the latest Flashplayer and Java. Javascripts are running, NoScript is off in YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that Google must be working on... it's just a 'link' issue (kind of).  In the mean time, if you go directly to the video you'll be able to add/edit annotations (top-right of the video) without much trouble (I'm not a fan of them personally ;) )